# Creating filter using org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject class

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am creating a jar file using org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject. while creating i would like to exclude few files from the selected directory based on the file extension.

```java
if (selectPackageCombo.getText().equals(item)) {
    IProject project = availableProjects.get(i);
    Package package = EclipsePackageRepository.instance().getPackage(project);
    if (package != null) {
        try {
            project.createFilter(IResourceFilterDescription.EXCLUDE_ALL| IResourceFilterDescription.FOLDERS|IResourceFilterDescription.FILES,
                                 new FileInfoMatcherDescription("org.eclipse.ui.ide.multiFilter", "1.0-name-matches-false-false-Test"),IResource.BACKGROUND_REFRESH, new NullProgressMonitor());
        } catch (CoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        jarData.setSelectedProject(project);
        jarData.setOutputSuffix(package.getPackageResource().getType());
    }
    break;
}
```

Please help me how to create the object of FileInfoMatcherDescription  to exclude all the files with the extension "**.ayt**"

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much informaton about this but it looks like you can work out the values by using the 'Resource Filters' page in the project properties and creating the filter you want. The id and arguments values will then be saved in the `.project` file in the project which you can read.

So for your requirement I get

```xml
<matcher>
    <id>org.eclipse.ui.ide.multiFilter</id>
    <arguments>1.0-name-matches-false-false-*.ayt</arguments>
</matcher>
```

so the constructor is

```java
new FileInfoMatcherDescription("org.eclipse.ui.ide.multiFilter", 
                               "1.0-name-matches-false-false-*.ayt")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .In fact i tried the same approach but the files with the extension  *.ayt is getting deleted permanently  from the source folder. What i am looking for is that i wanted to keep those files in source folder and would like to remove from the jar file only.

Comment: That isn't what the project filter does. What is `jarData`? What is `EclipsePackageRepository`?